# Nancy - return pdf stream via ajax

Tags: crystal-reports, nancy

Is there any sample out there how to return a pdf stream (e.g. generated by Crystal Report) from a nancy module via an ajax request?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "ajax request" and why it matters, but recently we had to solve similar problem - i.e. returning pdf, generated from other tool. We ended up using as a template [a binary processor](https://gist.github.com/grumpydev/4605541), utilizing [the content negotiation](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Content-Negotiation).

You can modify the binary processor to work with `application/pdf` MIME type and "pdf" file extensions, so it returns the proper response whenever the request has an Accept header of "application/pdf" or when the request is like http://example.com/reports/report.pdf.

Using this, and assuming you have `IReportEngine` with `Stream GetReportByName(string name)`, your module will look like (pseudo code):

```
Get["reports/{reportName}"] = _ => _engine.GetReportByName(_.reportName);
```

Comment: Do you by any chance have some code snippet to illustrate your answer. I am using Crystal report to generate a stream and it does not have any interface of IReportEngine type.

Comment: IReportEngine is just an example for your own interface/service which produces stream with the data. You can use whatever you want. The point of the answer is, that given a class which can produce stream, your module is very simple in terms of just returning this stream, and Nancy content negotiation will do the rest, if you implement some form of media range processor.